# Video file decryption in iOS

Tags: java, ios, encryption, aes

I have an application which gets encrypted video in compressed mode from a Java server. On the iOS side I'm not able to decrypt that.

The code I using for encryption in Java is:

```
    // generate a key
        KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keygen.init(128);  // To use 256 bit keys, you need the "unlimited strength" encryption policy files from Sun.
        //byte[] key = keygen.generateKey().getEncoded();
        byte key[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");


        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(key);

        // initialize the cipher for encrypt mode
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivspec);

        System.out.println();

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(new File(fileName))));
```

My code for decryption in iOS is the following:

```
       char  keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1];
bzero( keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr) );

[key getCString: keyPtr maxLength: sizeof(keyPtr) encoding: NSUTF16StringEncoding];
Byte iv [] =  {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

//unsigned char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

NSData *passwordData = [@"[B@71e2b67c" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;

NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *buffer_decrypt = malloc(bufferSize);

CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt( kCCDecrypt , kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                 passwordData.bytes, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                 iv,
                                 [self bytes], [self length],
                                 buffer_decrypt, bufferSize,
                                 &numBytesEncrypted );
NSLog(@".......decryption...........%d........",result);
if( result == kCCSuccess )
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer_decrypt length:numBytesEncrypted];
```

What might be the problem here and how can I solve it?

Comment: What happens when you try to decrypt? Do you get an error message? Do you just get the wrong result? Without some more information it will be difficult to help you with this problem.

Comment: Not getting any error while decrypting. but not decrypting the file.encrypted data is coming there.

Comment: Trying to decrypt video file, it will came in success block and return  data. but file getting is encrypted

Comment: So you're saying that the "decrypted" data you get, is actually still the encrypted data? Or is it different but incorrect?

Comment: A good way to try and debug this problem is to encrypt a small piece of known data (e.g. the ASCII bytes for `"Hello, World!"`), rather than an entire video file. If you can get the simple case working correctly, the file should also be fine.

Comment: Update your code correcting the items indicated in my answer and update your question code. Without that it is not possible to provide more help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The password is not the correct length for `kCCAlgorithmAES128`, it is 88 bits:

```
NSData *passwordData = [@"[B@71e2b67c" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

There is an inconsistency:

`kCCAlgorithmAES128` and `kCCKeySizeAES256`

The decryption key is not the same as the encryption key.
The decryption iv is not the same as the encryption iv.

Just for starters you need to get these correct.

As @Duncan writes, start with a very simple case and when that is working add complexity. A simple starting point is exactly one block of data, no padding, a simple key of the correct size, an iv of all 0s.

Best bet: hire a domain expert, security is very hard to get correct.

Comment: Thanks, now working fine, changed 7padding to No padding and keysize to kCCAlgorithmAES128